# Delay while reading message from BlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to add delay while reading message from BlockingQueue. when i added Sleep in consumer it is not going in sleep mode.

Producer Code:

```
public void run() {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !line.trim().isEmpty()) {
        queue.put(line);
        //queue.put(message);
    }
}
```

Consumer Code:

```
public void run() {
    try {
                while((msg= queue.poll(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) != null && msg.getExpireTime()>=System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            System.out.println(queue.size());
            System.err.println("str = " + msg);
            Long completionTime = 0L;
            switch(msg.getMessageType()){
                case UPDATE:completionTime = 450L;break;
                case ALERT:completionTime = 250L;break;
                case REMOVE:completionTime = 100L;break;
                case ADD:completionTime = 450L;break;
            }
            log.info(msg);
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(completionTime);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Thread waiting for "+completionTime +" ms");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Input:**

```
first line 450ms sleep
Second Line 450ms sleep
Third Line 100ms sleep
```

**Output:**

```
first line 
Third Line
Third Line
```

**Expected Output:**

```
first line 
Second Line 
Third Line
```

Comment: What do you mean by input, output here? Are you sure that completion time is set?

Comment: When i am taking the value from blockingqueue I am getting first line ,
Third Line,
Third Line, instead of first line ,
Second Line ,
Third Line.If i remove sleep line from consumer then i am getting proper result.So what will be the reason?

Comment: The code does not seem to allow to get the Third Line twice from the queue. Can you post a self-contained example?

Comment: It is impossible to understand your code - it is not consistent: producer produces Strings, but consumer expects some user-defined type with method getMessageType. Produces prints "str = " + msg, but expected output does not contain "str = ".

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a [DelayQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html). .take() blocks until the correct amout of time has passed for each element.